# Recommended GIT gui client, able to work on a custom-mapped port repository

Tags: git, repository, workflow, port, customization

I've installed git server in my private home environment.
Let's say that is on a port different than 80 ( for example 12345 ).

How can I make my day to day operations using my system in the port I mapped ?

I did not use 80, because I need it for something else

Can you guys recommend me a GUI Git that can work with my custom set-up ..

I'm currently looking at ... https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Answer (score 3):

You simply add as a remote url one using the port you have specified:

```
git remote add origin https://yourserver:12345/yourRepo.git
```

You would use a similar url in any of the GUI you might end up using.

git will then use that url for any git pull/push/fetch operation.

Comment: But is this when using a console from Unix ( directly execute a gitcommand ). I specified that I want to make it work using some kind of GUI, But I really do not know which GUI is the best for my case. I am currently using push-pull from terminal. I know it's easier trough the terminal under Unix, but my client is a Windows PC and the Server is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Which one do you recommend, that will support a custom port mapping ?

Comment: As long as the GUI accepts HTTPS URL, you are in business.

Comment: Yes it does accept these, but whenever I put the custom port it brings "git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)"

Comment: Tortoise Git executes "git.exe clone --progress -v" which is on the default port ( 80 ) It does not find any repository then crashes with 128

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров You should be able to put an url like `<server:port>`, which means that, even if there is no dedicated field for the port number, the port would still be specified as part of the server name.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing but it gives code 128, though in console works perfectly ;)

https_://gitlab.home.com:12345/root/test.git

Maybe I have to modify it to:

https_://root:password@gitlab.home.com:12345/root/test.git

Or something like that ....

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for git client recommendation, I would suggest TortoiseGit. One of the simple and most efficient tool, it integrates with Windows Explorer.

Comment: Already tried it. There is now way to put a custom port in there.

Comment: Few relevant posts which will help you to configure TortoiseGit :
http://serverfault.com/questions/109778/tortoisegit-with-non-default-ssh-port

http://codeslinging.blogspot.in/2010/01/setting-up-tortoisegit-to-work-with-ssh.html